# React: Accessing a target element as 'this'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events

This has probably been answered before, but I can't seem to google it as it overlaps a bit with `.bind(this)` questions.

What I want to do is to refer the calling element as `this` when I run a function e.g.

```
highlight()
{
  this.select();
}

<input value={final_line} onClick={this.highlight} ></input>
```

However, `this` is undefined after clicking it. So what would the best way to do this? Right now I'm using `event.target` as a replacement, which works. I've also seen `ref` being used, but am not sure if this is applicable as I am returning an array of `input`.

So my question overall is: Is there an alternative to using `event.target`?

Comment: change onClick={this.highlight} to onClick={this.highlight.bind(this)}

Comment: @Ved That's not what I want. if I `.bind(this)` it'll refer to the class itself, which isn't what I want. I want it to refer to the calling `input`.

Comment: You misunderstood use of  'this'. And what do you mean  refer to the calling input?

Comment: Like in standard javascript. If you do an `onclick="a_function()"` inside `a_function` if you call `this` it will refer to whatever called it, whether it's a button, input or div.

Comment: Correct. For this here you already using event.traget. That is correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

> So what would the best way to do this?

There is no way to do this. Using `event.target` is actually the right way to achieve it.

If you have several inputs, you should use the `name` property to identify the targeted element:

```
inputs.map(input =>
  <input name={input.name} onClick={this.highlight} />
)
```

```js
highlight(event) {
  this.setState({ [event.target.name]: 'clicked!' })
}
```

Comment: alright I'll just keep using it then. I just feel like I'm going to get a bug somewhere along the way because I will have another event thing that things it's activating or something :\

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Do you have an example? Maybe I could help.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with GG. - you should use `event.target`, but an alternative is to use [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import React from 'react';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { final_line } = this.props;

    return <input value={final_line}
      onClick={ this.highlight.bind(this)}
      ref="inputToHighlight"
    />;
  }

  highlight() {
    this.refs.inputToHighlight.select();
  }
}
```

Comment: For an array, you'll want to to use the [key](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html) attribute on the items as they're rendered. You can technically give them a dynamic `ref` and then do the lookup on `this.refs['inputToHighlight-' + index]` in your rendering of the array of items.

Comment: But you would probably want to grab from `e.target` in that case so you can do `e.target.key`.

Comment: But there is no point to use `refs` in this case. [That's a terrible practice.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs)

Comment: I agree GG - @A.Lau it may be better if you just tell people what you're trying to do from a high level. You're doing something wrong.

Comment: I've used refs when I had to have repeated components, each of which were forms with the same number of inputs. I don't feel like refs would be a good idea here, given the unknown number of elements that may go into the array. I'm not doing anything particularly difficult, I'm just more or less used to using `this` which I feel is safer than using `event`. Have no particular sources to backup my fear though.

Comment: If you dynamically assign refs by looping through the array in your JSX, then it doesn't matter what the size of the array is. The big issue is that you'd still rely on `event.target.key` to look up the ref anyhow. Dude just get over your irrational fear. I have a bunch of them so I sympathize with you, but following convention is a good thing in frameworks. :-P

Answer (score 1):

Use [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) inside an arrow function as your onClick to set this to event.target like:

```
onClick={ (event)=>{onClick.call(event.target, contact.id) }
```

Comment: Note: "contact.id" here is the first argument to the click handler.